# Как реализовать хлебные крошки (Bread crumbs) в приложении?

Tags: c#, uwp, prism

нужен элемент управления "хлебные крошки" для навигации в приложении. Приложение написано с помощью Prism. Понимаю, что надо распотрошить navigationService, но что конкретно надо сделать?

И еще как реализовать сам контрол. Я так понимаю, что это должен быть некий список с горизонтальной ориентацией и текстом в виде гиперлинков? А как сделать, чтобы средние ссылки прятались и оставались только первая и последняя, если все не влезают?

Comment: Ответьте, если вопрос ещё актуален

Comment: @AntonShakalo уже не актуально, но если знаете ответ, то хотелось бы расширить кругозор)